# How to install xap file on windows emulator and capture user actions

Tags: windows-phone-7, automated-tests

How to install xap file on windows emulator and capture user actions?

I need to write application in windows c# .NET and deploy xap file on windows emulator. How I can record button click or user actions on emulator in order to do automated testing.

Is any framework like calabash-android, gorillaMonkey, Appium for windows phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you specified "Install xap file" but I think you are looking for [Expensify](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework)

Good news is its free and open source, and records the user action to perform automated functional tests on emulator. you can find youtube demo video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JkJfHZDd2g)

This also supports Android and IOS so if you have same app for android and app you may reuse plenty of testing code.